# Make ProgressRing spin at least one rotation or revolution?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Is there a way to make the built in UWP `ProgressRing` spin for at least one revolution or rotation?

When trying to provide the user feedback when they press a button, i.e. they execute an operation, I want to be able show at least one revolution or rotation of the `ProgressRing`.

Comment: Can you please show the code you currently have that displays the `ProgressRing`?

Comment: Since the ProgressRing doesnt have a value like a ProgressBar you will probably be best to just hide it after a set amount of time has passed?